# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (opencv and python)

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm getting this error:

```
File "eye_motion_tracking.py", line 17
    _, contours, _= cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
                                                                                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("eye_recording.flv")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret is False:
        break

    roi = frame[269: 795, 537: 1416]
    rows, cols, _ = roi.shape
    gray_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_roi, (7, 7), 0)

    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_roi, 3, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
  _, contours, _= cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

    for cnt in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

        #cv2.drawContours(roi, [cnt], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(roi, (x + int(w/2), 0), (x + int(w/2), rows), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(roi, (0, y + int(h/2)), (cols, y + int(h/2)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        break

    cv2.imshow("Threshold", threshold)
    cv2.imshow("gray roi", gray_roi)
    cv2.imshow("Roi", roi)
    key = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error message, it's telling you where the problem is:

```
File "eye_motion_tracking.py", line 17
    _, contours, _= cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
                                                                                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

If you then look at that line, and assuming your posted code is the same as the actual code you have on your editor, it's clear that that line is not indented correctly.

```
    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_roi, 3, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
  _, contours, _= cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)
```

In Python, [indentation is important](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and make sure your code is not [mixing tabs with spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Just indent it properly and consistently.

```
    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_roi, 3, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    _, contours, _= cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)
```